# MCMC diagnostics for EMC or SMC

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, monte-carlo, diagnostic

Are diagnostics developed for MCMC (e.g. Gelman-Rubin, Geweke) suitable for output from Evolutionary Monte Carlo (EMC) or Sequential Monte Carlo (SMC)?